# Accessing a Closed Groups Feed via Facebook's Graph API

Tags: facebook, graph

Assuming a user authenticates appropriately, and is a member (note: not administrator) of a given group. Is it possible to access the feed of said group using Facebook's graph API?

Previous posts have suggested this is not possible with the introduction of the Graph API, however these are 2 years old and Facebook's documentation is less clear on the matter.

Comment: what have you tried so far? please include your research and code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation to read feeds of any group "A User access token for an Admin of the Group with the following permissions: user_managed_groups"

Source link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/group/feed